# how to delete an Instagram post to a hashtag

Tags: instagram, hashtag, instagram-api

I'm new to Instagram and Instagram development. My company wants to create a hashtag and have people submit photos to it, but able to curate those photos. That is, my company wants to be able to delete some submissions, or at least make them invisible in the hashtag feed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. You cannot control the use of a hashtag by other people in Instagram. Anyone can use your hashtag for 'irrelevant' photo and the only way to get it invisible from the hashtag feed is if the owner of a photo removes the hashtag from that particular photo.

Comment: OK, thank you, @John. Do you know how to curate what images would appear on an instagram feed?

Comment: No problem. Well, any image posted by the people you follow on Instagram will appear on your personal feed and you can't manage nor remove them. If you don't like a post, then you can simply unfollow the person who posted that image and the image will disappear from your feed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to delete Instagram post.

Please refer this link and download files from Github: 
https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

```
<?php
   require '../src/Instagram.php';
   /////// CONFIG ///////
   $username = '';
   $password = '';
   $debug    = false;
   $photo    = '';     // path to the photo
   $caption  = null;   // caption
   //////////////////////
   $insta = new Instagram($username, $password, $debug);

   try{
       $instaId = '1435464203242425768_3770950408'; //Like this post Id
       $reply = $insta->deleteMedia($instaId);
   }catch(Exception $g){
      $g->getMessage();
   }
```